# Delphi XE4 Pro THTTPRIO + https connection

Tags: delphi, ssl, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 Pro
I created a server DLL with webBroker and created the client DLL importing the server WSDL interface.
Everything works fine, but now I want to connect using a secure connection https.
On the server I have a valid *.domain SSL certificate issued by godaddy.
By simply changing the RIO URL to use https all client-server communications still work.

My question is: Do you know if now in XE4 THTTPRIO is capable to automatically handle https connections or I need to alter (somehow) the code?
Also, can you suggest a good tool to verify headers in order to see if in fact I'm using a good https connection?

Thank you very much..

```
function GetIHFSINET(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IHFSINET;
const
  defWSDL_server = 'https://etc';
  defURL_server  = 'https://etc';
  defSvc  = 'IHFSINETservice';
  defPrt  = 'IHFSINETPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
    Addr := defWSDL_server;  //there is actually a function that returns the correct URL to use
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IHFSINET);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: as far as the tool to analyze http requests I found Fiddler very useful [http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the URL to https is all you need to do - it will take care of the rest by changing the port to 443 etc.

As far as verifying the message you may want to look into RIO.OnBeforeExecute and RIO.OnAfterExecute events.

Comment: What is about server certificate validation?